# Unity Networking: Using syncliststring

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking

I have a Game Manager object marked as Server Only (on the Network Identity), which I want to keep track of neutral game objects in the game.

I need a way to sync a list to all clients when the list changes. So I've been trying to use SyncListString. However, because the Game Manager object doesn't exist on all clients, I'm getting this error "did not find target for SyncList message for x". Fair enough.

So I thought I would us a normal string list in the Game Manager object, with SyncListString on my player object, and update it using Command functions. However, I cannot set the SyncListString to equal the Game Manager list as they are different types.

Am I doing this wrong? is there a better way?

I'm very tempted to just put all of my code in Game Manager into my player script using isServer statements... maybe I should?

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question correctly, You should create the Game Manager object on every instance of the game.
then update your SyncListString with Command.

you can make your Game Manager static (singleton design pattern).

after that your static SyncListString is accessible from everywhere but updates to it has to be done in a Command function.

Comment: Cool thanks! So I untick the Game Manager 'Server Only' box on its Network Identity, so all objects have a copy. I've never heard of singleton design before.. why would I need to make the Game Manager static? Wouldn't having a syncListString (that is only updated via Commands) be enough?

Comment: well, you need one instance of game manager (and the list inside it)
imagine you have two game managers cause errors can happen. therefore you have two list. which one has the truth about your game world? it can mess things up.
It's a good practice to make these kind of things that by nature there should be only one of them singleton to avoid future possible problems.

Comment: Also, Would I require a SyncListString variable in my player script that references the SyncListString in GameManager? (Or should I make the Game manager SyncListString global?)

Comment: no. you need to make your list public static (it happens anyways if your game manager has a singleton pattern) and access it from anywhere you want. like 'GameManager.ListOfGameStuff.Add() ..'

Comment: At the moment, I have one instance of game manager per client. If I make it server only, I can't access the sync list from a non-host client.

Comment: I have tried making the Game manager syncliststring static, however I'm getting an error "Synclist .... cannot be static"

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried making the Game manager syncliststring static, however
>   I'm getting an error "Synclist .... cannot be static

You should make your class static not the list itself.
If you don't want to do that. just get a reference to Game Manager and use the list from there. (your list has to be public)

Comment: "static class GameManager cannot derive from NetworkBehaviour"

Comment: I managed to get it working without using static classes or variables. My problem now is SyncListStruct<T0> - know of any decent examples?

Comment: you should make a new question for that.